# How to create outlined Card widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to include a outlined material card with flutter, but since the card widget doesn't have a style element or something similar, I am not sure how to implement this.

I tried using the `shape:` property but wasn't very successful, mostly because I didn't understand how it works.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

It has `shape` property which takes a `Border` you can change that.

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40), // if you need this
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
      width: 1,
    ),
  ),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  ),
)
```

---

I think the screenshot you showed can also be achieved by just using `elevation` property of the `Card`.

Comment: What about the border radius?

Comment: Thank you! I just have a quick question, what would be an example for borderRadius?

Comment: In order to achieve the screenshot that I showed both, the elevation, and the shape property need to be changed. Only using the elevation would result in a card without border.